# What would be the preferred way to select the data to be displayed in the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here's my code:

```
private void LoadStudents()
{
    Int64 gradeInstanceId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbGradeInstance.SelectedValue);

    StudentInstanceRepository studentInstanceRepo = new StudentInstanceRepository();
    var studentInstances = studentInstanceRepo.FindAll()
                    .Where(s => s.GradeInstanceId == gradeInstanceId);

    StudentRepository studentRepo = new StudentRepository();
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    foreach (var item in studentInstances)
    {
        students.Add(studentRepo.FindStudent(item.StudentId));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = students;
}
```

When I set the datasource to students directly, all of the columns in the table is displayed. I only need to show for example, Name and LastName, both are attributes in the Student class.

How would I display this? Thanks!

---

**EDIT**:

This used to work on the previous version of the form:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = studentRepo.FindAll()
                          .Where(s => s.GradeParaleloId == gradeID)
                          .Select(s => new { Codigo = s.StudentId, RUDE = s.Rude, Nombre = s.Name + " " + s.LastNameFather + " " + s.LastNameMother, Telefono = s.Telephone });
```

The FindAll() method was just a return for IQueryable.

Why would that work before, and this new code doesn't?

Comment: Why are you finding the students again after you get the studentInstances already? Why this loop? foreach (var item in studentInstances)     {         students.Add(studentRepo.FindStudent(item.StudentId));     }

Comment: Because of the way the database is designed. There's the student table which holds a "catalogue" of sorts of all the students. Then there's the StudentInstance table, which is just a foreign key table that holds the StudentId and the Year. This is so I can easily get the grades of StudentX in year 2009 for example.

Comment: Alright.. Just check the DB Server trace/log for how many queries are being issued. I would suggest using something like contains clause with the studentInstances and students to reduce the SQL's issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = students.Select(a=> new{a.Name, a.LastName}).ToList();
```

Comment: When I try to run the application with this line no data is displayed in the DataGridView. When I use plain old 'students' it shows everything. the select seems to break it. Any suggestions?

Comment: From the given code snippet. I don't see anything wrong with the suggested change....

Comment: @Cybernate: I know, I don't see anything wrong with it either. Yet it's not displaying anything on the DataGridView. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you post the code where the dataGridView is being initalized etc?

Comment: @Cybernate: It's just a default dataGridView dragged from the toolbox. Nothing special during initializing. See edit please.

Comment: @Cybernate: It works, I just have to add a .ToList() clause to the end of the .Select statement. I'm accepting this answer, but please edit that last bit in so other people can find the solution. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Sergio: Updated the post. But am still not sure why IQueryable was not resulting the same result.

Comment: @Cybernate: The grid requires the entire data when you are assigning it as DataSource, if not its evaluated record by record which is not what the grid will require , so **ToList** or **ToGridview** comes in handy

Answer (score 0):

OK, first version kind of missed the mark (assuming ASP.NET). In WinForms just right-click on grid and "Edit Columns" and bind to this:

dataGridView1.DataSource = from s in studentInstanceRepo.FindAll() 
                              where s.GradeInstanceId == gradeInstanceId
                              select new { s.Name, s.LastName };

Comment: Got it missed that! Wouldn't build this with WinForms at this point however and code in WPF is similar in spirit. In WinForms, just do "Edit Columns" in designer!

Comment: The target machines that will run this application are pretty old - WPF isn't an option.